# Calling js function from inside a string in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a JS function from inside this code:

```
var myVar;   

myVar = "<hr>"+var1+"</hr><table><tr><td><a href='#' onclick='myFunc("+myVar+");'>Show</a></td></tr></table>";
```

The function is not being called and it seems to be because of the `"+myVar+"`,
 any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `myVar` has no value at that point. Did you mean to write `+var1+` instead?

Comment: Sorry, it should had something....still that's not the problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you are exactly trying to achieve with this ? It would be easier for others to suggest solution then.

Comment: Please try to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, ideally as something runnable so we can see exactly what's going on, perhaps as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).  Right now it's not clear how this is being output to your page, or exactly what variable you want to be passing - it doesn't make sense to be passing `myVar` and be assigning to it for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You must give the `myVar` in quotes:

```
onclick='myFunc(\""+myVar+"\");'
```

**Solution Explanation**

For those "geniuses" who downvoted blindly, without even being a part of the effort, thanks. Please find the explanation:

This is something like PHP's `$$var`, which is similar to `eval()` of JavaScript.

So, this part of code:

```
var myVar='sometext';

myVar = "<hr>"+var1+"</hr><table><tr><td><a href='#' onclick='myFunc("+myVar+");'>Show</a></td></tr></table>";
```

Gets translated into HTML as: (note:`<hr>` tag can't have inner html)

```
<hr>(var1-value)<table><tr><td><a href='#' onclick='myFunc(sometext);'>Show</a></td></tr></table>
```

But what happens here is, the `sometext` should be sent as a value and not as a variable.

To do that, we need to replace the `onclick` attribute this way:

```
onclick='myFunc(sometext);'    // Old
onclick='myFunc("sometext");'  // New
```

To make that, what I proposed is:

```
onclick='myFunc(\""+myVar+"\");'
```

This should help.

Comment: It's right, thanks for your answer and for the whole explanation,

Comment: @YosiTagger Please click on the tick mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this decision will suit you. Good luck.

```js
var myVar;   
var myVar2 = 'options';
var var1 = 'Test';

myVar = "<hr>"+var1+"</hr><table><tr><td><a href='#' onclick='myFunc(myVar2);'>Show</a></td></tr></table>";

document.write(myVar);

function myFunc(opt){
  alert(opt);
};
```